# Enable multi-az in aurora cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

i'm creating a rds using aws cloud formation template and i want the rds to deploy on multi az. i don't want to create cluster i want to deploy db instance with multi az. here is my code

```
"DatabasePrimaryInstance": {
      "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
      "Properties": {
         "AllocatedStorage": "200",

        "MultiAZ"           : true,
        "Engine": "aurora",
         "DBName":{
               "Ref":"DatabaseName"
            },
             "MasterUsername":{
               "Ref":"DatabaseUsername"
            },
            "MasterUserPassword":{
               "Ref":"DatabasePassword"
            },
          "PreferredBackupWindow":"02:00-03:00",
            "PreferredMaintenanceWindow":"mon:03:00-mon:04:00",
            "BackupRetentionPeriod":{
               "Ref":"DatabaseBackupRetentionPeriod"
            },
            "PubliclyAccessible": false,
        "DBInstanceIdentifier": { "Fn::If" : [ "CreateProdResources", "prod-db",  "uat-db" ]},
        "DBInstanceClass":   { "Fn::If" : [ "CreateProdResources", "db.r3.xlarge",  "db.r3.xlarge" ]},
        "DBSubnetGroupName": {
          "Ref": "DatabaseSubnetGroup"
        },
        "VPCSecurityGroups":[{"Ref": "DatabaseSecurityGroups"}]
      }

    }
```

when i run the template i get an error saying   VPC Multi-AZ DB Instances are not available for engine: aurora. what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing is correct. The combination you are trying to make is simply not possible.

You can only use one of the following scenarios:

- Use [Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html), and work **with** clusters. AWS will handle the multi AZ
  stuff
- Work with [non Aurora RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html), then you handle the multi AZ stuff.

Comment: yes. you're correct and im going with clusters. is it possible to make a cluster with one node having multi az?

Comment: No. If you want multi AZ, you need atleast two nodes. This is the same for Aurora as normal RDS mysql. The difference is that for Aurora, you actually see the second instance, while for normal RDS, the MultiAZ instance is created in the background and not visible for you.

Comment: i see. that's clear my confusion regarding two node visibility enabling multi az and aurora multi az works as master-slave replication right? or there is possibility for multi master nodes?

Comment: Right now only master-slave relations. but multi master is coming. In both cases, RDS and RDS Aurora, automatic failover happens when  MultiAZ has been setup.

Comment: @DasunHettiarachchi Aurora is not exactly the same thing as conventional master/slave, because the instances use the same disks (the Aurora Cluster Volume) so the master ("writer") role can be moved and applied to any instance in cluster, with a replica taking over automatically and becoming master if the master fails, and the old master automatically recovers and becomes a replica.  Unlike RDS Multi-AZ, with Aurora, all instances are accessible and you can read from all of them... with RDS Multi-AZ, where the standby machine is for recovery only, and not otherwise accessible to you.

Comment: i see. one more thing @Michael-sqlbot i was trying to enable cloud watch logs for aurora and i didn't see that feature enable yet for this RDS. do you have any suggestion regarding log management of aurora?

Comment: @DasunHettiarachchi like this?
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.CloudWatch.html

Comment: yeah but that's just the audit logs right? what about error logs etc